# UL menu with submenu using ListView

Tags: asp.net, listview, c#-3.0

I am using Asp.Net web-application.
Could you please help me to understand how exactly to create UL menu with ListView control such as :

```
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Item #1</a>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="#">SubItem #1</a>
    </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

Binding via DataSource works fine but cannot create tree and I need exactly HTML tree list as UL element.
Ideally it would be great to have recursive method in code behind which creates tree of ListViewItem and then I would add them to the ListView control in the cycle.
For now I would be happy at least to create few nested cycles where I could hardcode adding of items and subitems, but i had some stupid error when I try to create new ListViewItem object.

```
var lvi = new ListViewItem("Item #1");      // does not work
var lvdi = new ListViewDataItem("Item #1"); // does not work
AdminTopListView.Items.Add("Item #1");      // does not work
AdminTopListView.Items.Add("Item #1", 1);   // does not work
```

Error: cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListViewDataItem'

Though this says another: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview%28v=VS.90%29.aspx

**What is wrong, why I can't create ListViewItem and ListViewDataItem as MSDN says?**

And another question, I have ListView template with HTML A element inside and somehow 
I need to set its HREF attribute to some value.

**How can I set HREF attribute of anchor link inside ItemTemplate of ListView?**

This is template for ListView:

```
<asp:ListView 
     ID="AdminTopListView" 
     runat="server"
     onload="AdminTopListView_Load">
     <LayoutTemplate>
        <ul runat="server">
        <li id="AdminTopListView_PlaceHoler" runat="server"></li>
        </ul>
        </LayoutTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
        <li id="AdminTopListView_Item" runat="server">
            <a href="<%# Eval("RouteURL")%>"><%# Eval("RouteName")%></a>
        </li>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <SelectedItemTemplate>
        <li id="AdminTopListView_Item" runat="server">
            <a href="<%# Eval("RouteURL")%>"><%# Eval("RouteName")%></a>
        </li>
    </SelectedItemTemplate>
    <EmptyItemTemplate>
        <li id="AdminTopListView_Item" runat="server"><a href="#">No data</a></li>
    </EmptyItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

Thanks in advance. Any links and advices are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer - http://forums.asp.net/p/1620761/4161400.aspx#4161400